# Fri Jul 27 11:50:23 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:3 virt:76 mapped:0

Tags: mongodb

what is the meaning of this mongodb log ::

Fri Jul 27 11:50:23 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:3 virt:76 mapped:0

1. what is res ?.
2. what is virt ?.
3. what is mapped ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It tells you how much memory is currently in use :-

```
Res = Resident Memory Used (Physical Ram)
Vir = Virtual Memory Used
Mapped = Mapped memory used
```

[Checking Server Memory Usage - MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage) may help to explain further.

Comment: It appears that FAQ (singular) is not on the FAQ (plural) anymore.